# Каким способом правильно писать SFINAE в шаблонах? C++

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, sfinae

Заметил, что SFINAE в шаблонах пишет по-разному. Двумя способами:

```
template
<
    typename Func,
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_invocable_v<Func>, std::nullptr_t> = nullptr
>
```

И:

```
template
<
    typename Func,
    typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_invocable_v<Func>, std::nullptr_t>
>
```

Мне сказали, что первый способ лучше, но не объяснили чем и в чем разница между ними. Сказали что-то про невозможность подменить типы. Я примерно догадываюсь о чем речь, но можете ли объяснить подробнее, что тут происходит?

Comment: Второе вообще не является SFINAE, так как тип параметра шаблона по-умолчанию не является частью сигнатуры. Первое тоже не совсем SFINAE.

Comment: @user7860670 почему? Ведь здесь enable_if основан на SFINAE, он делает контролируемую ошибку, в случае несоответствия условия и шаблон исключается

Comment: Ну попробуйте сделать пару шаблонов такими способами

Comment: @user7860670 все создается, не понимаю к чему вы клоните. Говорите прямо, пожалуйста https://godbolt.org/z/ssj8qGdT9

Comment: В вашем примере SFINAE участия не принимает. Для SFINAE надо (как минимум) два шаблона, из которых при подстановке аргумента шаблона посредством SFINAE будет выбираться один. см https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae

Comment: @user7860670 я имел ввиду то, что enable_if позволяет также исключать шаблоны и он основан на SFINAE. В любом случае, в чем разница между двумя приведенными вариантами записи enable_if?

Comment: enable_if сам по себе не обязательно оборачивается SFINAE. Если шаблон только один и надо наложить условие на его параметры (как в вашем примере), то следует использовать static_assert и там концепты, а SFINAE при этом ни на каком этапе не понадобится.

Comment: @user7860670 хорошо, а можно все таки узнать в чем разница подобных записей Enable if и почему первый лучше?

Comment: Об этом я уже написал в первом комментарии.

Comment: @user7860670 `Второе вообще не является SFINAE, так как тип параметра шаблона по-умолчанию не является частью сигнатуры. Первое тоже не совсем SFINAE` я не хочу хамить, но терпение больше не позволяет. Можно по-проще и напрямую, пожалуйста, я не могу понять из этого сообщение почему первый вариант лучше и что происходит в данном коде

Comment: @user7860670 *"Второе вообще не является SFINAE ... не является частью сигнатуры"* Уж не знаю про сигнатуру, но SFINAE точно распространяется на аргументы по умолчанию.

Comment: *"Если шаблон только один ... следует использовать static_assert"* Как-то сомнительно. Никогда не знаешь, кто захочет проверить твой шаблон SFINAE. :) Не очень понял, почему `enable_if_t` противопоставляется концептам, ведь это почти одно и то же.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Во-первых, в первом способе нельзя выключить проверку, явно указав шаблонный аргумент, как уже написал Qwertiy.

Во-вторых, первый способ позволяет перегружать функцию, так чтобы отличалось только условие. Если попробовать это со вторым способом, компилятор будет ругаться на повторное определение функции.

В-третьих, первый способ не дает криворукому программисту инстанцировать шаблон несколько раз, указав разные шаблонные аргументы. Для этого нужен именно `nullptr_t`, потому что у него только одно возможное значение. Некоторые пишут первый способ с `int` `=0`, и он такой защиты уже не дает...

---

Но если вам доступен C++20, то лучше использовать `requires` вместо старомодного `std::enable_if_t`, или еще лучше - сокращенную запись с концептом, а-ля `std::invocable<...>` вместо `typename`.

`requires` и концпеты всем хорошы. У них те же плюсы, что и у `enable_if_t`, и плюс:

- Синтаксис удобнее.
- Перегруженные функции автоматически ранжируются по жесткости требований, если возможно. Пример:

  ```
  template <std::integral T> void foo(T) {}
  template <std::signed_integral T> void foo(T) {}
  ```

  Вызов `foo(1)` скомпилируется. Хотя у обоих функций условия выполняются, будет выбрана вторая, потому что у нее более жесткое условие. А если попробовать то же самое с `enable_if_t`, компилятор не сможет выбрать функцию и будет ругаться.

Минус один:

- `requires` проверяется позже, чем обычный SFINAE. Очень редко, но это может мешать. Пример:

  ```
  template <std::integral T>
  std::make_unsigned_t<T> foo(T t) {return t;}
  ```

  Эта функция написана плохо: ошибку `foo(1.f)` не отловить SFINAE, потому что `std::make_unsigned` сломается до того, как компилятор проверит концепт.

  Классический SFINAE здесь бы сработал, потому что был бы проверен до инстанцирования `make_unsigned`.

Comment: Очень подробный ответ, благодарю

Answer (score 4):

## Вызываем как положено `doSmth([]{})`

Первый код: https://godbolt.org/z/P4YGP95PY

```
#include <iostream>

template
<
  typename Func,
  std::enable_if_t<std::is_invocable_v<Func>, std::nullptr_t> = nullptr
>
void doSmth(Func&& callback)
{
  std::cout << (void*)&callback << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  doSmth([]{});
  return 0;
}
```

Второй: https://godbolt.org/z/sxvvP7G9v

```
#include <iostream>

template
<
  typename Func,
  typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_invocable_v<Func>, std::nullptr_t>
>
void doSmth(Func&& callback)
{
  std::cout << (void*)&callback << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  doSmth([]{});
  return 0;
}
```

## Передаём мусор: `doSmth(1)`

Первый код не компилируется: https://godbolt.org/z/E7T7385a4

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:15:9: error: no matching function for call to 'doSmth(int)'
   15 |   doSmth(1);
      |   ~~~~~~^~~
<source>:8:6: note: candidate: 'template<class Func, typename std::enable_if<is_invocable_v<Func>, std::nullptr_t>::type <anonymous> > void doSmth(Func&&)'
    8 | void doSmth(Func&& callback)
      |      ^~~~~~
<source>:8:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
<source>:6:65: error: no type named 'type' in 'struct std::enable_if<false, std::nullptr_t>'
    6 |   std::enable_if_t<std::is_invocable_v<Func>, std::nullptr_t> = nullptr
      |                                                                 ^~~~~~~
```

Второй код не компилируется: https://godbolt.org/z/d8j4K4GeE

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:15:9: error: no matching function for call to 'doSmth(int)'
   15 |   doSmth(1);
      |   ~~~~~~^~~
<source>:8:6: note: candidate: 'template<class Func, class> void doSmth(Func&&)'
    8 | void doSmth(Func&& callback)
      |      ^~~~~~
<source>:8:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-11.2.0/include/c++/11.2.0/bits/move.h:57,
                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-11.2.0/include/c++/11.2.0/bits/nested_exception.h:40,
                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-11.2.0/include/c++/11.2.0/exception:148,
                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-11.2.0/include/c++/11.2.0/ios:39,
                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-11.2.0/include/c++/11.2.0/ostream:38,
                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-11.2.0/include/c++/11.2.0/iostream:39,
                 from <source>:1:
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-11.2.0/include/c++/11.2.0/type_traits: In substitution of 'template<bool _Cond, class _Tp> using enable_if_t = typename std::enable_if::type [with bool _Cond = false; _Tp = std::nullptr_t]':
<source>:6:3:   required from here
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-11.2.0/include/c++/11.2.0/type_traits:2514:11: error: no type named 'type' in 'struct std::enable_if<false, std::nullptr_t>'
 2514 |     using enable_if_t = typename enable_if<_Cond, _Tp>::type;
      |           ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

## А теперь обходим защиту:

Только второй код: https://godbolt.org/z/9538fab81

```
doSmth<int, int>(1);
```

Код успешно компилируется и выводит:

```
0x7ffd6828091c
```

А вот способа такое провернуть с первым кодом я придумать не могу.

Comment: Да, это именно то, что я хотел услышать. Я так понимаю это работает из-за того, что во втором коде у нас не определен четко тип шаблонного параметра, а в первом случае мы задаем его жестко? Как раз то, о чем пытался сказать комментатор выше?

Comment: @ComeInRage, комментатор, наверное, тоже, но об этом даже у тебя в вопросе говорится: _"Сказали что-то про невозможность подменить типы"._